# How can I run a function on load as well as on button click?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to call the following method on my page load:

I'm not sure how to because its not a hardcoded named function like say 'function search()'

I realise there must be a easy way to do/reference this function using jQueryon my page

Many thanks for reading

```
$(function() {
    $('#searchButton').click(function() {
        var url = $('#AbsolutePath').val() + 'AuditLog.mvc/IndexSearch';
        var iPage = (parseInt($('#txtPage').val())).toString();

        var data = {
            StartDate: $('#StartDate').val(),
            EndDate: $('#EndDate').val(),
            sUser: $('#SearchTextBoxUser').val()
        };

        $('#txtPage').val(iPage);
        $("#ResultsList").load(url, data, function() {
            $('#LoadingGif').empty(); $("#paging").hide(); $("#paging").show();
        });

        LoadCharts(); 
        $('#LoadingGif').empty().html('<img src="' + $("#AbsolutePath").val() + 'Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading image" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: so, what part of it is the *"a JQUERY function thats named with JSON $ prefix notation"* and what in the world is *"JSON $ prefix notation"*?

Comment: Edited title to something that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is only executed on the `click` event ... if you want to execute on page load and the `click` event do this :

```
function processClickEvent() {
    var url = $('#AbsolutePath').val() + 'AuditLog.mvc/IndexSearch';
    var iPage = (parseInt($('#txtPage').val())).toString();
    var data = {
        StartDate: $('#StartDate').val(),
        EndDate: $('#EndDate').val(),
        sUser: $('#SearchTextBoxUser').val()
    };
    $('#txtPage').val(iPage);
    $("#ResultsList").load(url, data, function () {
        $('#LoadingGif').empty();
        $("#paging").hide();
        $("#paging").show();
    });
    LoadCharts();
    $('#LoadingGif').empty().html('<img src="' + $("#AbsolutePath").val() + 'Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading image" />');
}
$(function () {
    // execute on click event
    $('#searchButton').click(processClickEvent);
    // execute on load
    processClickEvent();
});
```

This seperates the code - I have created a new function `processClickEvent` then triggered its execution on the `click` event of `#searchButton` and also executed it on load